# WYSIWYG Редактор со встроенной подсветкой синтаксиса

Tags: wysiwyg, редактор

Мне нужен простой, но удобный WYSIWYG Редактор , **главное - чтобы была встроенная подсветка синтаксиса популярных языков программирования**, ну и что бы нормально работал в хроме, на остальные браузеры без разницы.

Answer (score 2):

Есть например [такой](http://ajaxorg.github.com/ace-builds/kitchen-sink.html) (http://ace.ajax.org/)